# bash - is there a pipefail automatic handler?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

i put below 2 lines at top of my shell script so it exits at any error

```
set -e
set -o pipefail
```

i then call my shell script as: 
chmod u+x /tmp/install_master.sh;/tmp/install_master.sh &>> /tmp/logs/install_master.log

if i want to ship the logs anytime the script exits with non-0 is best way to just interpret the return code like so?

```
chmod u+x /tmp/install_master.sh;/tmp/install_master.sh &>> /tmp/logs/install_master.log; rc=$? if [ rc -ne 0 ]; then aws s3 sync /tmp/logs/install_master.log s3://somewhere/; fi
```

or is there some inbuilt on_pipefail trigger that i could use?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'if' you could use logical operators

```
chmod u+x /tmp/install_master.sh &> /tmp/logs/install_master.log  && \
/tmp/install_master.sh &>> /tmp/logs/install_master.log || \
aws s3 sync /tmp/logs/install_master.log s3://somewhere/
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `install_master.sh` returns a non-zero exit status if it fails, then you could use || to check for non-zero exit status.

```sh
chmod u+x /tmp/install_masther.sh
/tmp/install_master.sh &>>/tmp/logs/install_master.log || {
  aws s3 sync /tmp/logs/install_master.log s3://somewhere/
}
```

I don't think pipefail is even a factor here, as it isn't a pipeline.